# Mouse not connected in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, vhd, hyper-v

Took a VS 2005 VHD connected it to Hyper-V, uninstall Virtual Machine Additions and installed Hyper-V Integration Components. Now mouse point shows arrow rather than dot, but you cannot click anywhere in this W2003 SP2 image whether on the W2008R2 Hyper-V server or by using RDC.

Rebooted host and guest, zippo, mouse does not work.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you RPD into it instead?  I find it much better to use RDP to connect, rather than the Hyper-V Connection Manager.